# Issues with using box-shadow for text background over multiple lines

Tags: html, css

I'm used to using box-shadow as a way to give backgrounds to text headings, and have made use of the trick of applying a box-shadow to a  within  tags for a neat "background with padding" highlight effect for headings that go over multiple lines, with the background aligning to the end of the span instead of the heading block element. The following code used to create an effect like the picture below.

[image]

```
h1.highlight span {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 16px #fff000;
        background-color: #fff000;
        line-height: 1.6;
        box-decoration-break: clone;
    }

<h1 class="highlight"><span>Highlight text<br />goes here</span></h1>
```

However in the past couple of months, I've noticed that this trick no longer works and the box-shadow affect once again breaks when the heading goes to a second line as here: https://codepen.io/georgiacobrien/pen/LYBbJge

Firstly, does anyone know why this is now being rendered differently and 2. Is there a better way to be getting the same effect for heading that go over multiple lines?

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly/how it should look like, but a `span` is an inline-element, so you might want to add `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` to your CSS (?)

Comment: @Johannes I've updated my question with an image to better illustrate: if I change it to block or inline-block, the background goes behind the whole thing like a big yellow box, instead of clipping to the words as in the picture I've added. I used this trick for years but no longer works, so looking to see how I can easily recreate the same look.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is a Chrome/webkit quirk. I've always used box-decoration-break: clone; without prefixes to no issue on Chrome, but it now seems you need to use with webkit prefix (-webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;) for this to work. Weird but there you go!